# Does Firebird BLR contain the related field sizes?

Tags: stored-procedures, size, field, firebird

Firebird and InterBase keep a compiled form of stored procedures and triggers in BLR (tokenized) format.

But I do not really know the structure of BLR.

Is field size the part of the BLR?

Would I get some problems when a stored procedure contains two fields (source and destination), and later I'll change the size of these two fields?

For example they were `varchar(50)` long, but now I change them to `varchar(100)` with system table updates. What will happen? Would it only copy 50 characters, or all (100)?

Or does BLR contains only object links (tables and fields)?

I will try to demonstrate with "pseudo" code:

```
begin
  for select comp_id, comp_name from companies where ...
    into :ci, :cn 
    do begin
      -- somehow we're adding this to another table
      insert into new_clients (id, name) values (:ci, :cn);
    end
end;
```

This could be a trigger or stored procedure.

1. `Comp_name`, and `new_clients.name` are initially `varchar(50)`.
2. I add this procedure or trigger. It is working fine for a day.
3. Later I realize these fields are too short to fit my data.
4. I use a GUI (for example IBExpert) to change these fields to `varchar(150)`.
5. It's ok, all of them are `varchar(150)` now.

Then what will happen?

1. If BLR contains field sizes too, then it doesn't matter I changed the fields' sizes. The trigger copy on 50 characters, cos it has precompiled prior length.
2. If BLR uses only relates/links/tokens to the tables and fields, we can change the fields without worrying of copy function.

The question is same: does BLR contains the related fields' sizes or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you can see BLR of a procedure in ISQL:

```
SQL> create or alter procedure p1 (i1 varchar(10), i2 varchar(20)) returns (o1 varchar(30)) as begin end!
SQL> set blob all!
SQL> commit!
SQL> select rdb$procedure_blr from rdb$procedures where rdb$procedure_name = 'P1'!

blr_version5,
blr_begin,
   blr_message, 0, 4,0,
      blr_varying2, 0,0, 10,0,
      blr_short, 0,
      blr_varying2, 0,0, 20,0,
      blr_short, 0,
   blr_message, 1, 3,0,
      blr_varying2, 0,0, 30,0,
      blr_short, 0,
      blr_short, 0,
   blr_receive, 0,
    ...
blr_eoc
```

Second, don't, ever, change system tables.

Third, yes, you'll have a problem! It's why there is no `ALTER PROCEDURE PARAMETER` command.

Comment: Your answer was ok, but I meant fields and not paramters. I revisited the question... Sorry for misunderstandable content.

Comment: You can check the BLR as I pointed you. But no matter it work or not, I still don't recommend system table changes.