# Firebird, decrypt stored procedure?

Tags: stored-procedures, encryption, firebird

I got myself into a place where I need to port some functionality from a legacy Firebird database into MSSQL. The table schema and data was ok, all was enumerable and selectable for sysdba, however, the application layer is proving to be a pain. 
The database has some 1000+ procedures and I would like to to move them over with some review rather than rebuilding the whole DAL. The problem is (you guessed) that they all appear to be encrypted somehow. When I ask to alter it to generate a script I get the ALTER script but the body of the procedure looks like a base64 string of some binary content. My first guess is encryption.

Is there some way to decrypt those bodies, like there is for MSSQL? Please note that Firebird database is running on its original box, in its original Firebird installation, nothing has been copied or moved, in case access to some keys is required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create (or alter) a stored procedure in Firebird, Firebird will store the original body in column `RDB$PROCEDURE_SOURCE` of table `RDB$PROCEDURES`. This will not be encrypted. This body is not relevant for Firebird itself, as it will use the compiled form of the stored procedure (in column `RDB$PROCEDURE_BLR`); it is only stored to allow isql (and other tools) to generate the DDL script of the database.

Some software vendors don't like that people have access to their sourcecode, and so they will either null this `RDB$PROCEDURE_SOURCE` column or - as is likely the case with your database - encrypt the body in some way.

If this is an application that was developed in-house, you will need to find the original scripts used to build this database.

Otherwise there is no way to undo this without knowing exactly what the vendor (or developer) has done. Another possible solution would be to reverse engineer to stored procedure from the BLR (Binary Language Representation, the compiled form of the stored procedure), but I am not aware of tools that do this (and this might not result in very readable code).

Doing either of these might violate the license agreement, and maybe even local law. Your best bet would be to contact the vendor of this legacy application and ask (or pay) them for this source code.

The ISQL tool can print the BLR in 'readable' form, but as it is very low-level, I don't know how helpful that will be. For an example see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16134109/466862).

Comment: There are no legal problems for the company afaik, the software was commissioned and paid for at some point in the past, so afaik the company owns it. And you are right, the source column is encrypted, which kind of explains other (non dev) issues we are having with the ex-contractor and their behavior. I am just going to present all this to legal and let them deal with this first. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score -1):

Since Firebird 3.0, database encryption is now possible ...so it has nothing to do with the Firebird installation, rather the database it self was already encrypted, I'm afraid you'll need the encryption keys to decrypt the data read these articles:

http://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/en/3_0/rnfb30-security-encryption.html

http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/CORE-657

Comment: This answer doesn't address the problem of the question. Database encryption is at a lower-level which prevents read-access to the database itself without the decryption key. If Firebird 3 database encryption would be involved, then the database would either be entirely inaccessible, or the source would be readable, because it would be decrypted automatically on read.