# Can't view stored procedure source code in firebird

Tags: database, stored-procedures, firebird, isql

I'm using firebird 3.0 database with some stored procedures. Let's say i want to check the definition (sql code) of procedure SP_CALC.

I've tried ISQL:
show procedure SP_CALC;

I've also tried using Database Workbench (demo version)

In both cases i cant view the source code of stored procedure. I can see just the definition of input and output columns, but I need to see how this procedure works.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is this a stored procedure you created yourself, or is this a database where the vendor has removed or otherwise obfuscated the stored procedure source code?

Comment: It's a third part database, not my own creation. So It's possible that its previous owner had obfuscated the source code. Is there any way to get it back?

Comment: You can verify if the code is really gone by using `select * from rdb$procedures`. If the column `RDB$PROCEDURE_SOURCE` is empty, it was intentionally removed (if it is not empty, then you might have hit a bug in Firebird 3). There is no (easy) way to recover the source code. See also my recent answer to a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37189966/466862

Comment: @BojowyZajaczek, Why not contact software vendor if you have  questions related to calculations? Respect others work.